# How to explicitly set default language in wagtail?

Tags: python, django, internationalization, wagtail

I have a website which has 2 languages. Everything works perfect but i just need to set the default language for every user. Users can change the language if they want but i want to serve the website in default language.
I've made some search and found that maybe i can do it with django.views.i18n.set_language() but couldn't find how.
Any help would be great.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you have `USE_I18N = True` in your settings file?

Comment: @kbdev yes, i do.

Answer (score 0):

In your settings file, set `LANGUAGE_CODE` to the desired language. As documented at [How Django discovers language preference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference), Django selects this as the default language when no preference has been set in the user session or browser settings.

Comment: i've already defined it. i don't know what i am doing wrong. :\